# Get the last modification time of file

Tags: command-line, regex

I want to extract the stretch `Jul 22` from the output :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 douglas douglas  92188 Jul 22 08:47 master-terfron-21-07.log
```

This is the output of the command:

```
ls -l *.log
```

How would i use a regular expression to get the required portion?

Comment: Whats the final goal? To extract the last modified month and date of any file?

Comment: Hello, I want the file creation date.

Comment: Thats the last modification date of the file, not the file creation date..

Comment: I understand, but it also meets me at the moment

Comment: Do something like `find . -name *.log -printf "%Ab %Ad"`.

Comment: All right then..you are satisfied with the last modification month and date e.g. `Jul 3` ?

Answer (score 5):

As you want only the last modification time (month and date) of the `.log` files in the current directory you can simply use the `-r` option of `date`. There is no need for any regex or other superfluous commands.

You can use this shell one-liner :

```
for i in *.log; do echo "$i: $(date '+%b-%d' -r "$i")"; done
```

For example i am finding the month and date of last modification of all `.txt` files in the current directory :

```
$ for i in *.txt; do echo "$i: $(date '+%b-%d' -r "$i")"; done
file.txt: Feb-12
new.txt: Jul-23
```

The main command involved here is :

```
date '+%b-%d' -r file.txt

$ date '+%b-%d' -r file.txt 
Feb-12
```

If you want to do the operation recursively, use `find` :

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%p: ' -exec date '+%b-%d' -r {} \;
```

**Example :**

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%p: ' -exec date '+%b-%d' -r {} \;
./foo/list.txt: Jul-16
./new.txt: Jul-15
./file.txt: Jul-23
```

**EDIT :**

For the sake of answering the original `regex` way :

```
$ ls -l *.txt | grep -Po '.*[[:digit:]]+ \K[[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{2}'
Jul 23
Jul 15
```

- `grep -Po` indicates we will use PCRE and only take the matched portion
- `.*[[:digit:]]+` matches upto our desired portion and `\K` discards the match
- `[[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{2}` matches three alphabetic characters (month) followed by a space and two digits (date).

Answer (score 3):

To get the last modification date of your file you can use:

```
$ stat -c '%n: %y' *.log
alternatives.log: 2015-07-20 09:28:52.727063510 +0200
apport.log: 2015-07-23 09:32:58.282590564 +0200
```

See the [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/stat.1.html) man page for further options.

Comment: Sylvain, i have also thought this primarily but OP wants the output in a specific format i.e. `%b-%d` or perhaps `%b %d`..

Comment: @heemayl I've updated my answer, but I still prefer your `date -r` ;)

Comment: Yeah, `date -r` seems simpler to me too in this case.. +1..  :)

Comment: You don't need to call stat in a loop, a single invocation will work: `stat -c '%n: %y' *.log` -- I wish the "human readable" timestamp was configurable though

Comment: The awk answer will not provide the correct output if the filename contains spaces. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @glennjackman: indeed, good catch. I've updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'd use `stat --printf="%y"` in a script if I had to dump it into a variable or pass further. I'd rather use `%Y` (seconds passed since epoch) instead of `%y` and convert to format and timezone of my choice. Loved this solution by the way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution to use `ls` with `cut`:

```
ls -l filename | cut -f 6,7 -d' '
```

example:

```
$ touch file
$ ls -l file | cut -f 6,7 -d' '
Jul 23
```

Another solution:

```
 ls -l filename |awk {'print $9" was last modified   "$6" "$7'}
```

Comment: Will not provide the correct output if the filename contains spaces. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)